# change color of a cell in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, datagridview

```
protected void gvSC_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string stext = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    stext = stext.Trim();
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((e.Row.Cells[i].Text).ToString() == stext)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here even though if condition satisfies, the program control is not going inside and executing forecolor statement

Comment: Have you checked in debugger if its condition satisfies?

Comment: yes i checked.. both have same string only... thanks for reply..

Comment: Try `(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).Trim()` in case any white spaces at last which is getting unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).Trim()` in case any white spaces at last which are getting unnoticed.